# Chrome extension getUserMedia not working in background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, navigator

I am making a chrome extension that will allow recording screen but I want to do this in background script without even opening options page. How can I achieve this in chrome extension. I can see other extensions like loom are able to do so

I tried injecting script in tab but as soon as tab closes screen sharing disappears. I also tried to use getUserMedia or desktopapture in background.js but It didnot work

Comment: "Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from secure origins: HTTPS or localhost." --- are you running the request from a secure origin?

Comment: @Jridyard I am trying to access it from background.js script in extension

Comment: Not sure where it would fall, but technically background.js origin is `chrome-extension://${chrome_extension_identifier}` - that technically isnt HTTPS nor localhost.

Comment: So there is no way we can get access to navigator object in background.js or keep the stream running even if the tab is closed. I am very new to extensions so do not know much

Comment: I looked at vimeo's chrome extension source code and found a call to `chrome.desktopCapture` made from background.js. This is likely what you are looking for, see documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/ --- I also saw calls to `getUserMedia` and `executeScript` as a heads up though. But consider looking at the documentation for desktopCapture first.

Comment: Are they also using options page

Comment: Install this extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en) - after installing, go to vimeo (or any other recording tool) and click the chrome extension source viewer's icon and click the "download source code" button. You will have a zip of the source code for that extension and can look through the code to research your project further.

Comment: Also, if you don't know about obfuscation/deobfuscation there are 2 tools to try to make the code more readable: Basic unminifier: https://www.unminify2.com/ --- Advanced deobsfucator: https://deobfuscate.io/